# Wrong indexation elasticsearch using the analyser

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I did a pretty simple test. I build a student index and a type, then I define a mapping:

```
POST student
{

    "mappings" : {
        "ing3" : {
            "properties" : {
                "quote": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "english"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that I add 3 students to this index:

```
POST /student/ing3/1
{
  "name": "Smith",
  "first_name" : "John",
  "quote" : "Learning is so cool!!"
}

POST /student/ing3/2
{
  "name": "Roosevelt",
  "first_name" : "Franklin",
  "quote" : "I learn everyday"
}

POST /student/ing3/3
{
  "name": "Black",
  "first_name" : "Mike",
  "quote" : "I learned a lot at school"
}
```

At this point I thought that the english tokeniser will tokenise all the word in my quotes so if I'm making a search like:

```
GET /etudiant/ing3/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "quote" : "learn" }
    }
}
```

I will have all the document as a result since my tokeniser will make equal "learn, learning, learned" and I was right. But when I try this request:

```
GET /student/ing3/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "quote" : "learned" }
    }
}
```

I got zero hit and in my opinion I should have the 3rd document (at least?). But for me Elasticsearch is also supposed to index `learned` and `learning` not only `learn`. Am I wrong? Is my request wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check:

```
GET 'index/_analyze?field=quote' -d "I learned a lot at school"
```

you will see that your sentence is analyzed as:

```
{
   "tokens":[
      {
         "token":"i",
         "start_offset":0,
         "end_offset":1,
         "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
         "position":0
      },
      {
         "token":"learn",
         "start_offset":2,
         "end_offset":9,
         "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
         "position":1
      },
      {
         "token":"lot",
         "start_offset":12,
         "end_offset":15,
         "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
         "position":3
      },
      {
         "token":"school",
         "start_offset":19,
         "end_offset":25,
         "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
         "position":5
      }
   ]
}
```

So english analyzer removes punctions and stop words and tokenize words in their root form.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-language-analyzers.html

You can use `match` query which will also analyze your search text so will match:

```
GET /etudiant/ing3/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : { "quote" : "learned" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way. You can **both** stem the terms (the `english` analyzer does have a stemmer), but also keep the original terms, by using a [`keyword_repeat` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-repeat-tokenfilter.html) and then using a [`unique` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/analysis-unique-tokenfilter.html) with `"only_on_same_position": true` to remove unnecessary duplicates after the stemming:

```
PUT student
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "myAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop",
            "keyword_repeat",
            "english_stemmer",
            "unique_stem"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "unique_stem": {
          "type": "unique",
          "only_on_same_position": true
        },
        "english_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        },
        "english_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "english"
        },
        "english_possessive_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "possessive_english"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "ing3": {
      "properties": {
        "quote": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "myAnalyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case the `term` query will work, as well. If you look at what terms are actually being indexed:

```
GET /student/_search
{
  "fielddata_fields": ["quote"]
}
```

it will be clear why now it matches:

```
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "student",
        "_type": "ing3",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "name": "Roosevelt",
           "first_name": "Franklin",
           "quote": "I learn everyday"
        },
        "fields": {
           "quote": [
              "everydai",
              "everyday",
              "i",
              "learn"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "student",
        "_type": "ing3",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "name": "Smith",
           "first_name": "John",
           "quote": "Learning is so cool!!"
        },
        "fields": {
           "quote": [
              "cool",
              "learn",
              "learning",
              "so"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "student",
        "_type": "ing3",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "name": "Black",
           "first_name": "Mike",
           "quote": "I learned a lot at school"
        },
        "fields": {
           "quote": [
              "i",
              "learn",
              "learned",
              "lot",
              "school"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
```